# How to add a timeout to detect that an Observable didn't emit for a while

Tags: rx-java

My use-case is following:

I created an Observable to access a remote server to fetch some data. However there could be no response and no exception from it forever due to the fact that the server is not well-designed. To work this around I want to have some timeout-with-retry mechanism.

Currently I try to initiate a timer to stop the request and throw the exception inside it and then retry until certain number of attempts or my real timeout. I tried to use `mergeWith` operator to merge the reqeust with `Observable.interval` mapped to generate errors using `Observable.error()`, however I can't get the error being captured in the subscriber and it looks like the `Observable.interval` never ends.

How should I deal with this situation with any operator in RXJAVA ?

My current code looks like this:

```java
Observable.fromEmitter(fetchNetwork->...)
.mergeWith(Observable.interval(...)
           .flatmap(n->(observable.error)))
.retryWhen(error->(checkTimeExceed))
.subscribe(handleResult)
```

Comment: Try to improve question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `timeout()` operator together with `retryWhen()`:

```
Observable.fromEmitter(fetchNetwork->...)
     .timeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
     .retryWhen(observable -> observable.flatMap(error -> {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutException) {
                    return Observable.just(new Object());
                } else {
                    return Observable.error(error);
                }
            }))
     .subscribe(handleResult)
```

this will timeout the request after TIMEOUT_VALUE seconds, and will retry as long the request was timeout, other errors will be propagate as usual to the subscriber `onError()`.

Comment: i don't see how the timer get restart somewhere ?

Comment: That's what retryWhen does, in the case of timeout it will resubscribe again, with the configured timeout

Comment: @yosriz cannot resolve symbol "fromEmitter", i guess it is depracet. I assume it can be any other operator like "just"?

Comment: @okset, yes this api changes above RxJava 1.3, it's now `create`, but this answer doesn't referring this operator specifically