# Kotlin and RxJava type inference failed

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, type-inference, rx-java2

I am trying to implement retryWhen on my Observable when there is ocurring a timeot, but i have strange errors underlined in IDE Android Studio 3.0

Here is the code:

```
rxRssiRepository.onRssiUpdate() //returns Observable<RssiEvent>
        .timeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .retryWhen { t: Observable<Throwable> ->
            t.flatMap { error: Throwable ->
                if (error is TimeoutException) {
                    stopLocationUpdates()
                    Log.v("TIMEOUT", "TIMEOUT RSSI EVENTS")
                    Observable.just(Observable.empty())
                } else {
                    Observable.error(error)
                }
            }
        }
        .concatMap { t: RssiEvent ->
            appendRssiEvent(t)
        }
        .publish()
```

The IDE underlines on red the .flatMap operator and says:

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter R in
>
> fun  flatMap
>   (
>   mapper: ((t: Throwable) → ObservableSource)!
>   )
>   : Observable!
>   Please specify it explicitly.

Same for the 'if' operator:

> Type inference for control flow expression failed. Please specify its type explicitly

For operator .just:

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in 
>   fun  just
>   (
>   item: T!
>   )
>   : Observable!
>   Please specify it explicitly.

For operator .empty:

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in
>
> fun  just
>   (
>   item: T!
>   )
>   : Observable!
>   Please specify it explicitly.

And for the .error operator:

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in
>
> fun  error
>   (
>   exception: Throwable!
>   )
>   : Observable!
>   Please specify it explicitly.

How to fix this?

I mean, this code was also here in Java:
[How to add a timeout to detect that an Observable didn't emit for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805481/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-detect-that-an-observable-didnt-emit-for-a-while)

But when i convert it similiary to Kotlin, it gives me the described situation issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler can't figure out what type you want to return.

The easiest fix in your case would be to add a type your return type. Something like this `Observable.just(Observable.empty<Any>())`. Now the compiler will be able to figure out what type to return.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, when this timeout occurs it dispose the host Observable, which i don't want to happen. Maybe you know how to prevent it? I mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805481/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-detect-that-an-observable-didnt-emit-for-a-while

Comment: `retryWhen` should resubscribe to the source observable and yes the original source finishes with error because of the `timeout`. I don't know how to get around it.